# Function to return a polynomial string format in clojure

Tags: clojure

I am working on a polynomial program where I have to return a string representation of a polynomial as the output in clojure... however i am having difficulty in implementing the function. So below are the specifications:

Sample input 1: (format-poly [3 "x" 4])

Output: "3x^4"

Sample input 2: (format-poly [2 "x" 0])

Output: "2"

Sample input 3: (format-poly[1 "x" 4])

Output: "x^4"

Sample input 4: (format-poly[0 "x" 3])

Output: nil

My function implementation so far:

```
(defn format-poly[polyterm]
   
        (clojure.string/join (str (first polyterm) (second polyterm) "^" ) (str(nth polyterm 3)))
    
    )
```

Comment: `str/join` takes one argument to just join strings or two for joining with a something else than space; in any case the last arguments has to be a collection of the things to join.  How do you expect all your special cases to be addressed without using any conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will take a vector containing multiplicand, variable name, and power and return the formatted string:

```
(defn format_poly [[mult var pow]]
  (format "%d%s^%d" mult var pow))
```

For example,

```
(format_poly [3 "x" 4])
```

returns a string containing

```
3x^4
```

### EDIT

```
(defn format-poly [[mult var pow]]
  (case pow
     0    (case mult
             0    nil
             (format "%d" mult))
     1    (case mult
             0    nil
             1    var
             (format "%d%s" mult var))
    (case mult
       0    nil
       1    (format "%s^%d" var pow)
       (format "%d%s^%d" mult var pow))))
```

which produces

```
user=> (format-poly [3 "x" 4])
"3x^4"
user=> (format-poly [2 "x" 0])
"2"
user=> (format-poly[1 "x" 4])
"x^4"
user=> (format-poly[0 "x" 3])
nil
```

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly but it works:

```
(defn format_poly [[mult vari pow]]
  (let [m (if (and (= 1 mult) (not= pow 0)) nil mult)
        p (if (or (= 0 pow) (= 1 pow)) nil pow)
        v (if (zero? pow) nil vari)
        c (if (or (= pow 1) (nil? v)) nil "^")]
    (if m
      (if (zero? m) 0 (str m v c p))
      (str m v c p))))

(format_poly [3 "x" 4]) ; 3x^4
(format_poly [2 "x" 0]) ; 2
(format_poly [1 "x" 4]) ; x^4
(format_poly [0 "x" 3]) ; 0
(format_poly [2 "x" 1]) ; 2x
(format_poly [0 "x" 0]) ; 0
(format_poly [1 "x" 0]) ; 1
(format_poly [1 "x" 1]) ; x
```